# How to get a list of the files that were written in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to get a list of the exact files that were written as the result of a Spark dataframe `save` API command. I'm specifically using `append` mode to update a common set of partitions and would like to know which files were added with every operation.

Example, with base data:

```
val jsonString   = """[
{"eventId": 1, "date": "20210101", "attributes": ["test", "foo", "bar"]},
{"eventId": 2, "date": "20210101", "attributes": ["test", "foo", "bar"]},
{"eventId": 3, "date": "20210101", "attributes": ["test", "foo", "bar"]},
{"eventId": 4, "date": "20210101", "attributes": ["test", "foo", "bar", "baz", "bro"]}]
```

**Load and save once**

```
spark.read.json(Seq(jsonString).toDS)
  .write
  .mode("append")
  .json("s3://bucket/test")
```

**Load, modify, and save again**

```
spark.read.json(Seq(jsonString).toDS)
  .withColumn("modified", lit("yes"))
  .write
  .mode("append")
  .json("s3://bucket/test")
```

How do I know which files came from which dataframe operation?

I'm on EMR dealing purely with S3 for what it is worth.

Answer (score 1):

You asked about files but you may wish to actually do away with partitions in S3 and use a better storage format like avro/ORC/Parquet.  Directory Scanning performs poorly in S3, it's better at throughput of large files.  You may get better performance storing massive files and using spark(CPU) to search the files rather than using million of small partitions. (That incur S3 performance hits as it searches for the small files.)

I have seen performance increases of %1000 in S3 by removing partitions and using large files.  This doesn't answer your direct question but if the underlying question is how do a I get better performance this is your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a column that is "updateTimestamp" and just pull the data you need from teh data frame?  I'm not sure you actually want to deal with files, just the data that was included.  If you added updateTimestamp and actually added a [table partition](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.2/sql-programming-guide.html) then you would be grouping the data (in the files system) together.

Comment: I would like to avoid re-reading the entire dataset, seems excessive. If I wanted to I could re-read the filenames with `input_file_name` as a new column. But I truly am interested in the files themselves.

Comment: I stand by my answer Partitions does what you are trying to do. (Here's a better description of what paritioning does at the file level: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.2/sql-programming-guide.html#partition-discovery)

Comment: I understand the Partitions API. I'm talking specifically about `append`ing data within partitions. So I may have the same base thousand partitions but millions of files across them. Filtering prefixes could work if I added additional partitions but that too requires a large scan in s3. I would just like to see if Spark can tell me what was written.

Comment: S3 is a poor choice for regularly writing/reading data into spark. It's better as long term storage because of it's poor performance in scanning.  There has been lots of work to try and make it reasonable to use but it really just doesn't perform well.  If you are trying to work around this performance issue I'd suggest doing some research on the specific topic.  As for your original question the answer is paritions is how spark knows where to look for specific data.  It does not have a ledger it records what data it put into which file.